# Breaking down a 'Join Not Supported' code, still running into issues

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to get this particular code to work by breaking it down into smaller bits to see what the issue may be for a SQL query

```
select tt.tk, tk2, count(*), count(a2.tk) / count(*) as ratio
from ((select distinct a.TK, a2.TK as tk2
       from access6 as a inner join
            access6 as a2 
            on (a.DocumentNo = a2.DocumentNo)
       where a.TK <> a2.TK
      ) tt left join
      access6 as a
      on (a.tk = tt.tk)
     )  left join
     access6 as a2
     on (a2.tk = tt.tk2 and a2.DocumentNo = a.DocumentNo)
group by tk, tk2;
```

If I run it as

```
(select distinct a.TK, a2.TK as tk2
       from access6 as a inner join
            access6 as a2 
            on (a.DocumentNo = a2.DocumentNo)
       where a.TK <> a2.TK
      ) tt left join
      access6 as a
      on (a.tk = tt.tk)
```

it says "Syntax error in Union Query"

The first portion of the select works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

first part of sql it must be `inner join` in `from access6 as a **join**`

second sql, you can only join tables in a `From` clause. So 
`) tt left join
      access6 as a`

wouldn't work unless the whole part comes under a `FROM` clause.

Comment: So I've been playing around with changing tt left join access6 as a to more along the lines of )) as tt left join access6 as a on (a.tk=tt.tk); and it's telling me that there's an error in the FROM clause. Is there a more correct formatting of LEFT JOIN that I'm missing for the FROM to be fixed?